# How to list objects by extension from s3 api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can i somehow search objects in S3 by extension, not only by prefix?

Here is what i have now:

```
ListObjectsResponse r = s3Client.ListObjects(new Amazon.S3.Model.ListObjectsRequest()
{
    BucketName = BucketName,
    Marker = marker,
    Prefix = folder, 
    MaxKeys = 1000
});
```

So, I need to list all *.xls files in my bucket.

Comment: You could just use AWS CLI (or do it from a process spawned in python): `aws s3 ls s3://some/folder --recursive | grep "\.csv" > s3-csv.txt`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible with S3.

The best solution is to 'index' S3 using a database (Sql Server, MySql, SimpleDB etc) and do your queries against that.

Comment: If this is still the best answer, I'd like to extend the question to wonder how the db is getting updated info of changes to the the bucket. Suppose a modern MS server stack: PowerShell script could provide the contact points for passing AWS stuff into SQL? Demoed anywhere?

Comment: @Steve - there wouldn't be any automated way for the DB to get changes from S3. If you had control over adding/removing files in S3, you'd just update the DB at the same time. Otherwise, you'll need to periodically scan S3 and update your index. We use the first method - so whenever someone uploads to S3 we create a corresponding entry in our db, pointing to the file and any other info we need. Then, instead of listing files(eg your `xls` files) directly from S3, we'll query the DB for any `xls` files, show those to the user and only access S3 when we actually want to download the file.

Comment: It heavily depends on your bucket structure and data you are storing:  indexing is not always --easily-- feasible.

Answer (score 24):

While I do think the *BEST* answer is to use a database to keep track of your files for you, I also think its an incredible pain in the ass. I was working within python with boto3, and this is the solution I came up with.

It's not elegant, but it will work. List all the files, and then filter it down to a list of the ones with the "suffix"/"extension" that you want in code.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'my-bucket'
prefix = 'my-prefix/foo/bar'
paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)

file_names = []

for response in response_iterator:
    for object_data in response['Contents']:
        key = object_data['Key']
        if key.endswith('.json'):
            file_names.append(key)

print file_names
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually need a separate database to do this for you.

S3 gives you the ability to list objects in a bucket with a certain prefix.  Your dilemma is that the ".xls" extension is at the end of the file name, therefore, prefix search doesn't help you.  However, when you put the file into the bucket, you can change the object name so that the prefix contains the file type (for example: XLS-myfile.xls).  Then, you can use the S3 API listObjects and pass a prefix of "XLS".

Answer (score 2):

I'm iterating after fetching the file information. End result will be in **dict**

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')

#get all files information from buket
files = bucket.objects.all()

# create empty list for final information
files_information = []

# your known extensions list. we will compare file names with this list
extensions = ['png', 'jpg', 'txt', 'docx']

# Iterate throgh 'files', convert to dict. and add extension key.
for file in files:
    if file.key[-3:] in extensions:
        files_information.append({'file_name' : file.key, 'extension' : file.key[-3:]})
    else:
        files_information.append({'file_name' : file.key, 'extension' : 'unknown'})


print files_information
```

Comment: This is valid answer which might be usable for some SO readers, so I upvote.
However, for me goal was not to read list of all files since I have millions of them.

Comment: @st78 thanks! that's right. for lots of data, I would rather use page limits. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because by using boto3 resource to get objects from S3, you can get satisfied result by using the returned file extension to filter what you want. Like this:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')
files = my_bucket.objects.all()
file_list = []
for file in files:
    if file.key.endswith('.docx'):
         file_list.append(file.key)
```

You can change the endswith string with what you want.

Answer (score 1):

if you're simply searching you can probably find them by using a combination of `awscli` and `grep` as follows:

`aws s3 ls s3://<your-bucket-name> --recursive | grep <your-file-extension>`

Answer (score 1):

I believe it could help someone.

I did find a way to do that using the [ends_with](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#ends-with) JMESPath function.

In my case specifically, I was trying to get the prefix and suffix at same time, this worked for me:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query "Contents[?ends_with(Key, 'my-suffix')]" --prefix "my-prefix"
```

If you only need the suffix:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query "Contents[?ends_with(Key, 'my-suffix')].Key"
```

For some reason, if the `--prefix` flag isn't set and if "my-suffix" value have a number (e.g. "mp4", "mp3") it won't work. But if the suffix value don't have a number (e.g. "json", "sh", "txt") OR the `--prefix` flag is seted it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following approach to search objects by suffix which is based on fetching a list of all the objects in the bucket and path specified (recursively; including sub directories) and then filtering out on the basis of suffix provided:

```bash
aws s3 ls s3://[BUCKET_NAME]/[DIRECTORY_NAME]/ --recursive | grep "[SUFFIX]"
```

Depending upon the above approach, I implement a similar solution in the desired programming language.

Looking at the code you mentioned in the question, it seems like it is `C# (.NET)`. So, in your case, the solution will be as follows:

```cs
var request = new ListObjectsRequest
{
    BucketName = [BUCKET_NAME],
    Prefix = [DIRECTORY_NAME],
    MaxKeys = 1000
};

ListObjectsResponse response;

string marker = null;

do
{
    request.Marker = marker;

    response = s3Client.ListObjects(request);

    var filteredObjects = response.S3Objects
        .FindAll(obj => obj.Key.EndsWith("[SUFFIX]"));

    foreach (var obj in filteredObjects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Object Key: {obj.Key}, Size: {obj.Size}");
    }

    marker = response.NextMarker;
} while (response.IsTruncated);
```

*Note: Don't forget to replace `[BUCKET_NAME]`, `[DIRECTORY_NAME]`, and `[SUFFIX]` in the code snippets mentioned above. Also, it is assumed that all the necessary libraries for AWS SDK have been imported and the AWS S3 client already exists in the code.*

Answer (score -2):

You can easily list all the elements by extension, getting all the elements (including folders) and then filtering by key.endswith('...')

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('your-route')

# Data from S3 is also filtered by endswith from key property
for _ in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=test_dir):
   if _.key.endswith('.zicu'):
      print('Value of object: ', _.key)
```

In this case I'm filtering each element with a Prefix (test_dir) and then showing just the elements with .zicu extension