# Boto3 Python Get only certain file types?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have

```
data = list(bucket.objects)
```

this will get me all of the objects in my aws s3 bucket
I want to be able to get only certain file types, such as a .png file.
i tried doing something like

```
data = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix = '*.png'))
```

but no luck. Any tips?

Comment: Prefix isn't going to work, because you are looking for the suffix, not the prefix. S3 doesn't index files by file extension, so you can't really do what you are asking without indexing the files via some other service. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709071/how-to-list-objects-by-extension-from-s3-api

Answer (score 2):

I guess the following should help:

```
client=boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key,region_name)
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')

page_iterator_1 = paginator.paginate(Bucket='bucket-name',PaginationConfig={'PageSize':1})
page_iterator = page_iterator_1.search("Contents[?contains(Key,'png')].Key")

for page in page_iterator:
    print(page) # will contain the entire response
```

Comment: `page_iterator_1.search()` happens client side unlike the filtering that happens using `Prefix`. For those looking for more information on that, see [official boto3 page] (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html) on filtering and [JMESPath documentation](https://jmespath.org/).