# Include only .gz extension files from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to process/download .gz files from S3 bucket. There are more than 10,000 files on S3 so I am using

```
import boto3
 
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
objects = bucket.objects.all()
 
for object in objects:
    print(object.key)
```

This lists .txt files which I want to avoid. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list objects by extension from s3 api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709071/how-to-list-objects-by-extension-from-s3-api)

Comment: well, I did something mentioned here - https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/134

Comment: What type of processing are you doing on the files? Amazon S3 Select or Amazon Athena might be useful, based on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to filter objects by name or suffix is to do it within Python, such as using `.endswith()` to include/exclude objects.

You can `Filter` by Prefix, but not by suffix.